# CitiBank or HSBC account in India but use funds in America

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, international, international-transfer

I have some money in India that I plan to transfer to an international bank such as Citi or HSBC. Once the money is in the account, can I use those funds in America? Are there any tax liabilities in the US?

Comment: What is you tax residency in US and India. Are these your own funds?

Comment: Hello, I am a US citizen. Yes, the funds are savings from when I used to live in India.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated where the funds are held. They should ideally be held in NRO account. If you haven't, have this done ASAP. Once the funds are in NRO account, you can repatriate this outside of India subject to a limit of 1 million USD. A CA certificate is required. Please contact your Indian Bank and they should be able to guide you.

There are no tax implications of this in US as much as I know, someone else may post the US tax aspect.